# Flask - put contents of a html page into the centre of a template page

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

I've only just started using Flask. I have a file with a series of links. It's generated by a separate script that returns something along the lines of this

```
<li><a href="foo1">foo1 Name </a></li>
<li><a href="foo2">foo2 Name </a></li>
<li><a href="foo3">foo3 Name </a></li>
<li><a href="foo4">foo4 Name </a></li>
```

which I save in a filewithlinks.html file in the templates folder

I want to do something like this

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h2>The Links</h2>
<ul>
{% extends "filewithlinks.html">
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

but when I try that it throws an error. for the {% extends "filewithlinks.html"> %}
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only extend one template at a time. For everything else, use [macros](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#import) or [include statements](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include).

For your list, using `{% include %}` is just the ticket:

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h2>The Links</h2>
<ul>
{% include "filewithlinks.html">
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the links in too.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`include`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include) macro. Replace:

```
<ul>
    {% extends "filewithlinks.html">
</ul>
```

with:

```
<ul>
    {% include 'filewithlinks.html' %}
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, I found the answer immediately after posting this by searching two templates in one page. Thanks anyways!